# Visual Studio 2012 Load Test is ignoring Step Count

Tags: visual-studio-2012, load-testing

I'm running a Load Test in Visual Studio 2012 which is based on a Web Test. The Web Test runs fine, but when I'm executing the Load Test, it seems to be ignoring the Step Load Pattern. I currently have it set as follows:

- Initial User Count: 3
- Maximum User Count: 200
- Pattern: Step
- Step Duration (seconds): 10
- Step Ramp Time (seconds): 0
- Step User Count: 1

I'm using the Test Mix Type of "Based on the total number of tests"

The Load Test is running for a total of 2 minutes which means that it should have a total of 14 tests that were run instead it varies wildly from one run to the next.

The first load time had a total of 45 tests, the second ran 42, and the third one ran 34.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? How can I get the step count to be properly enforced?

Answer (score 1):

Two minutes duration is very short for a load test. In two minutes there are 12 lots of 10 seconds, so the maximum user count at completion will be {initial}+{number of steps}*{step user count} = 3+12*1 = 37, ie much less than the 200 maximum specified.

Tests normally run with randomised think times, also the test themselves do different things and so may take different times. Choosing which test is run "next" at any given time is random but biased by the test mix type. Hence the number of test that may be executed is quite variable.

For the first 10 seconds 3 tests are executing.
For the second 10 seconds 4 tests are executing.
For the 3rd 10 seconds 5 tests are executing.
And so on.
If the test duration were known then it would be possible to estimate how many tests would be executed.
Given that at the finish there are 37 active users and given that the numbers of test on various runs were 34, 42 and 45 it would appear that the individual test duration averages a little less than 2 minutes.

To check whether the step pattern is being followed look at the graphs. You would expect the "users" (red line) in the "key indicators" to increase as the test runs. Another way is to look at the "details" results page where you should see horizontal lines corresponding to each virtual user.

Comment: I agree with Adrian.  Another thing to note about using a step pattern with certain models;  The user load is representative of virtual users being available to test, not necessarily that they are actively executing tests yet.  Another way you can see this is by adding the "passed tests" to you key indicators (for your initialize test.)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a7ef73b9-0df4-4381-816a-cb434f4750e9/getting-initialize-test-to-match-user-load-rampin?forum=vstest#fbcfd93c-a491-4a62-866b-eef46ce68487